# Does "provides" refer to the "wiggle room given to the timelines"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**[SOURCE](https://www.sciencealert.com/rey-kurzweil-s-most-exciting-predictions-about-the-future-of-humanity?perpetual=yes&limitstart=1)**

With a little wiggle room given to the timelines the author, inventor, computer scientist, futurist, and director of engineering at Google provides, a full 86 percent of his predictions - including the fall of the Soviet Union, the growth of the internet, and the ability of computers to beat humans at chess - have come to fruition.

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> With a little **wiggle room** given to the timelines the author, inventor, computer scientist, futurist, and director of engineering at Google provide**d**, a full 86 percent of his predictions - including the fall of the Soviet Union, the growth of the internet, and the ability of computers to beat humans at chess - have come to fruition.

"*provided*" refers to "*timelines*"

> ...given... the timelines...provided... his predictions...have come to fruition

"*wiggle room*" refers to the fact the the timelines are *close* but not *exact* in predictions.

Comment: I accept it's *possible* to convert ***provided*** to past tense, but personally I think present tense ***provides*** is more natural anyway. I certainly can't see any justification for arbitrarily changing that aspect in your answer.

Comment: The timelines would have had to occur *before* the prediction's fruition.

Comment: [The 2011 Census **provides** a high quality estimate of the population that people can use with confidence.](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/bulletins/2011censuspopulationestimatesfortheunitedkingdom/2012-12-17) It's perfectly normal to refer to such things using present tense, *particularly* when the "past" provision is relevant to the present moment, as here. I don't say your line of reasoning or choice of tense is *wrong* - just that the change is at the very least *unnecessary* in OP's cited example.

Comment: That's an interesting example and I see your point, I would characterize it as "The 2011 Census **provided** an accurate snapshot of the population which **provides** valuable data for *future* planning".

Comment: I would take "provides" to be an acceptable use of the habitual present - as a futurist, he habitually provides timelines for many predictions.

Comment: <soapbox-mode> Acceptable and preferable, even if not in the least habitual.  He made them.  He published them.  Those actions may well have stopped.  Given that the timelines are now public, he's hardly in a position to *stop providing* them.  They can go out of print, but they can't wink out of existence.  Neither is a published census able to stop providing that snapshot.  Neither is Homer able to stop providing insight into Ancient Greek culture.  It would require nothing short of the end of literacy, if not the end of the word, to move *those* actions into the past tense.  </soapbox-mode>